# make does not find arm-linux-androideabi-nm

Tags: android, linux-kernel, makefile, gnu-make

I'm experiencing this weird error when trying to build a kernel for my Samsung device:

`/home/aureljared/android/kernel/msm/scripts/mksysmap: line 44: ~/android/kernel/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: No such file or directory`

I've tried issuing `ls ~/android/kernel/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin` which just tells me that `arm-linux-androideabi-nm` exists.

I've also tried changing `$CROSS_COMPILE` to reflect an absolute path, e.g. `/home/aureljared` instead of `~/`, to no avail.

Extensive Googling has told me that there are also other Android developers who have experienced this issue, but were able to solve it and did not share the solution.

Is it possible that one of my [recent commits](https://github.com/aureljared/android_kernel_samsung_msm8930-common/commits/experimental) triggered the issue? Or is it something else? I'm really lost.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: What is the ouput of "ls -l /home/aureljared/android/kernel/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin" ?. 
Why not export the bin path ? export PATH=$PATH:/home/aureljared/android/kernel/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/

Comment: `ls -l /home/aureljared/android/kernel/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin` shows me all the binaries, all under `-rwxr-xr-x 1 aureljared aureljared`. I'll try the `export` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to answer this late than never!

I too faced the problem but i found my solution!

In kernel's Makefile, give the path fully:

/home/username/some-path-to-toolchains/bin/arm-eabi-

Instead of using this not working path:

~/kernel/that-don't-work/bin/arm-eabi-

Hope it helps!